# working with nginx and xip.io causing redirect issue

Tags: laravel, nginx, google-oauth, nuxt.js, xip.io

SO I am testing out an app doing oauth with google.  Don't have a domain for them yet but I can somewhat get it to work with xip.io.  I'd like to see if I can use Nginx to direct and redirect traffic from xip.io.   Right Now the test works but I have to manually remove the xio.io after the call from the browser, in other words.

The application starts here:

- http://IP-Address:3000/login/
- When you hit log in, it makes a call to http://IPAddress.xip.io:8001/api/login/google
- I have to manually remove the .xio.io and the app can continue.
- Google authorizes and redirects back to http://IP-Address.xip.io:8001/api/login/google/callback?.......
- I again have to remove the xip.io so that the app continues.

I'd like to be able to somehow have Nginx maybe intercept this request and redirect them so I don't have to remove the xip.io from the URL so that the app can proceed.

any thoughts?